# Setting figure pan and zoom state

Tags: matlab, zooming, matlab-figure, pan

I know that I can set the zoom state of a MATLAB figure using, for example, the following code:

```
zoom on;
zoom(2); % zoom in 2x
```

What I would like to achieve is to zoom in at a specific position of the figure, which I would specify as co-ordinates. How would I do this? I presume there must be some command which allows you to specify the figure pan position.

Comment: One possible solution exists on Matlab Central and can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/123876), ps also, doesn't the `zoom` function have an options structure containing a "Direction" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set(gca,'xlim',[minx maxx],'ylim',[miny maxy])
```